# django/javascript populating table on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

I have a huge database with multiple tables. Essentially I want the table I have to populate on the fly based on what the user clicks from a menu that is populated from the same database. I'm new to django and don't really know how to go about doing this. Right now all the information I need is being passed to the page when it renders and because of that my page is loading extremely slowly. Basically I have a function that is called when something from the menu is clicked that loops through everything I have passed to the page to populate the table accordingly.

To give you a better picture, let's say I have a table of stores and another table of the monthly revenue in my database. The table on the webpage will display the latest 5 data points (ie, the date (month and year), the revenue, and the store name). How do I populate the table based on the selection from the menu?

My menu is populated as follows:

```
{% for a, storeList in stores.items %}
    <div class="overview">
        <div><b>{{a}}</b></div>
        {% for s in storeList %}
            <div id = "{{s.storename}}"  onclick="changeSiteInfo(this.id);"{{s.storename}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try integrating [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) using one of the apps descirbed [here](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/tables/).

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try!